# twisted connectTCP memory leak？

Tags: memory, twisted, memory-leaks

I found my program have a memory leak when I used connectTCP.

```
<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> 
   <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('10.25.76.117', 8086) at 2066c5b0>
<type 'dict'> 
   {'_tempDataBuffer': [], 'protocol': None, '_tempDataLen': 0, 'realAddress': ('10
<type 'tuple'> 
   ('10.25.76.117', 8086)
<type 'list'> 
   []
<type 'instancemethod'> 
   <bound method Client.doConnect of <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('10
<type 'instancemethod'> 
   <bound method Client.doConnect of <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('10
<type 'tuple'> 
   ('10.25.76.117', 8086)

gc: collectable <Client 2066c770>
gc: collectable <dict 2066e4b0>
gc: collectable <tuple 206fa1e8>
gc: collectable <list 206478c8>
gc: collectable <instancemethod 206699b8>
gc: collectable <instancemethod 2046a6e8>
gc: collectable <tuple 206fa918>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a coherent question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.apparatusproject.org/blog/page/3/